# How to disable GoogleMobileAds after user makes in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I used CocoaPods to install the needed frameworks, put the bannerView on the top of the first cell of the UITableView and everything is fine. But I also want to implement an in-app purchase to disable the ads. I have read this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial) but it didn't explain how to do it for removing ads.

Answer (score 0):

Most people tackle this by setting a `userDefault` bool "hasPayed" and set it to true if the user makes the purchase otherwise keep it false.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasPayed")
```

Edit: Name the default as appropriate, the name for it is arbitrary

Comment: And how should be Admob disabled?

Comment: I haven't used the GoogleMobileAds framework so  don't know if there are nay additional flag you may need to set but aside from that, based on your explanation, removing the ad isn't just removing the banner view (e.g. `bannerView.removeFromSuperview()`)?

Comment: Well using the default.  You would load the view and write an if statement.  In paeduocode:  if userDefsult ==True, don't show the ad.  Else show the add.